# How do I switch from XNA to C++?

Tags: xna, c++, directx

So, I heard somewhere that Microsoft intends to phase out XNA in favour of using the DirectX method. I've always wanted to learn, but all I ever did in XNA was simple 2D games. I was wondering if there's any good tutorials out there for people migrating from XNA...thanks in advanced!

Comment: Unfortunately MS isn't all too clear about the future of XNA but it might not be the safest bet to invest time in XNA. However since you've worked with XNA you probably have a lot of experience with C#, a shame to let that go to waste. Why not try SlimDX or SharpDX? These two wrappers let you use DirectX from C# and are a lot faster than XNA. Of course you still need to learn DirectX but that's only one new thing at a time :)

Comment: @RoyT: Can you quantify "a lot faster than XNA"? I'm quite curious, as XNA isn't exactly un-optimised.

Comment: Do I even need any 3rd party libraries? There are DirectX DLLs in my computer under "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\"...?

Comment: @Jack: Look at this answer: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/17654/288

Comment: So...it's simply old a depricated? What would MS have me do, then? Surely they would rather I use their stuff directly than a 3rd party's library? Don't get me wrong, I absolutely love XNA, and I'd much rather do any programming through C#, but there's no version for Visual Studio 2012, and they've said that there won't be.

Comment: @AndrewRussell this page is the source of that statement http://code4k.blogspot.nl/2011/03/benchmarking-cnet-direct3d-11-apis-vs.html note the blog is associated with SharpDX but the benchmarks can be downloaded and run by anyone.

Comment: @RoyT Heh - I spot problems in that benchmark code. Although it looks like others have as well. There's a correction at the top of that article about issues in the benchmarking - so I'm not sure if I'm looking at the broken or fixed version of the code here :\

Comment: The graphs look to be from the old version, XNA should only have a 4x amplification factor not a 9x factor.

Comment: Yep - saw that. I wonder how much of it is "DirectX 9 vs DirectX 11", and how much is "XNA-being-helpuful" overhead, and how much is down to the marshalling that the article discusses. It doesn't surprise me that XNA is slower - I expect it takes hits in all three areas. Although it's worth pointing out, for anyone coming across this, that this is a micro-benchmark of *just* the API layer. Using XNA doesn't make your *whole* game 1.5-3x slower (vs the other managed libraries - native is a different beast).

Comment: @Jack I don't think I've ever seen them say that there *won't* be a version of XNA for VS2012? I'm not sure I've heard them say *anything* concrete about the future of XNA (annoying, yes?)

Comment: -1 Not constructive. Asking for "good tutorials" has no correct answer. You're just generating a list for a broad topic.

Comment: Well they are pushing C++ and JS for Windows 8 and as much as nobody said that XNA is definitively dead, if it's not being advertised then i wouldn't keep my fingers crossed. Personally if i was going to switch from XNA i'd pick either Java with OpenGL (for the language similarities and portability) or C++ with Direct3D or OpenGL (for portability and Windows 8 metro support). With Java you can target Android. with C++ you can get on Steam for Linux which is a top spot on Valve's priority list right now.

Comment: `So, I heard somewhere that Microsoft intends to phase out XNA in favour of using the DirectX method.` Please provide a source.  Otherwise, your entire question is being asked on the basis of rumors and hearsay.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you feel constrained by XNA 4.0 capabilities there is no really reason to switch from it to DirectX. At least you can try [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) which is actually recommended by [MS employee](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/37340/9166) (that can be a fake account of course, but I see no reasons to doubt it). The migration to MonoGame is pretty straightforward.

If you are making simple games there is no really need for pure DirectX. You also can be overwhelmed by technical details required for it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial that perhaps is going to be useful for you. Is about starting Managed DirectX applications and 2D, (you'll finde code there also). Hoping it helps.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3470/Managed-DirectX-Tutorial-Part-1-The-Title-Screen
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3601/Managed-DirectX-Tutorial-Part-2-Samus-Running

Answer (score 0):

Although this site is extremely ugly the tutorials are really in helpful and easy to follow. [Rastertek](http://rastertek.com/tutindex.html)